# How to find percent of values within 95% confidence interval in stata?

Tags: stata

I'm given a set of predictions and want to see what percent of these predictions are within the 95% confidence interval of TE (true effect).

I tried using r(Obs) - the same way you would use R(mean), but when I ran this code below, the 'var'totalobs and 'var'obsin95 are empty.
Is there an easier way to do this? Or way to make sure that the r(Obs) actually stores one scaler number?

// #2: CONFIDENCE INTERVAL.
//this is the total number of observations
sum `var'_prediction gen` var'totalobs = r(Obs)

```
// this is the total number of observations within the TE confidence interval
sum `var'_prediction if `var'_prediction < `var'_TE + 1.96 *`var'_se & `var'_prediction > `var'_TE - 1.96* `var'_se 
g `var'obsin95 = r(Obs)
// percent of observatins in confidnece interval is observations in confidnece interval / total observations 
g `var'percentinCI = `var'obsin95/ `var'totalobs
```

Comment: `r(Obs)` in your first command is only defined if some previous command defined it.. It's not illegal to refer to an r-class result that is not defined, but the result will always be returned as missing.

Comment: Note that a confidence interval at 95% wouldn't typically include that fraction of the data.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - scalar:** In case you want the result as a printed output you can do

```
gen within_TE = `var'_prediction < (`var'_TE + 1.96 * `var'_se) & ///
    `var'_prediction > (`var'_TE - 1.96 * `var'_se)

sum within_TE, meanonly
// show the percentage as a percentage
di "`=`r(mean)'*100' % of the predictions are within the CI of the TE"
```

The first line generates a 0-1 variable that is 1 if your prediction is in the confidence interval and 0 otherwise, the second line shows the mean of that variable. Multiplying the mean by 100 gives you the percentage.

**Option 2 - variable:** I am currently not on my computer with Stata, so I cannot check whether option 3 is working as well.

```
gen within_TE = `var'_prediction < (`var'_TE + 1.96 * `var'_se) & ///
    `var'_prediction > (`var'_TE - 1.96 * `var'_se)

egen nominator = total(within_TE) // sum of obs in CI of TE
egen denominator = count(within_TE) // number of obs
gen percent_in_CI = nominator / denominator * 100

drop nominator denominator
```

**Option 3 - variable:** I saw this when scrolling through the `egen` [help](https://www.stata.com/manuals/degen.pdf) file

```
gen within_TE = `var'_prediction < (`var'_TE + 1.96 * `var'_se) & ///
    `var'_prediction > (`var'_TE - 1.96 * `var'_se)

egen percent_in_CI = pc(within_TE)
```

Comment: Another question- is there a way to combine all the percent_in_CI values for each of 5 variables into one table (e.g. two columns- one is the name of the variable, and the other is the percent_in_CI value of that variable)?